# stop counter on data attribute for multiple values

Tags: javascript, html

I have many divs that contain an data-attribute with a different value for each

I try to print this value by counting using javascript

```js
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
console.log(numbers);
let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
 numbers.forEach((number) => {
        if(counter === number.dataset.num){
            clearInterval();
        }else{
            counter += 1;
            number.innerHTML = counter + "%";
        }
    })
}, 20);
```

```html
<div class="skill-level position-absolute">
            <div class="outer">
              <div class="inner d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="number" data-num="95">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
              <defs>
                <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
                </linearGradient>
              </defs>
              <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </svg>
          </div>
                    <div class="skill-level position-absolute">
            <div class="outer">
              <div class="inner d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="number" data-num="70">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
              <defs>
                <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
                </linearGradient>
              </defs>
              <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </svg>
          </div>
```

The problem is that the counter doesn't stop on the data-num value it counts to infinity

How can i stop the counter for each one in the value of data-num for each div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that both elements are referencing the same variable `counter`, so the variable is actually incremented by two every call of the function. Therefore, you should have counters for each number. Likewise, you should have intervals for each number so you know when to stop incrementing.

Also, you need to replace `number.dataset.num` with `parseInt(number.dataset.num)` because that attribute is actually a string. As Parsa S said, you should also use classes instead of ids. After implementing all of the changes, here is the code:

```js
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number"); // Change the HTML to use classes
const counters = Array(numbers.length);
const intervals = Array(numbers.length);
counters.fill(0);

numbers.forEach((number, index) => {
  intervals[index] = setInterval(() => {
    if (counters[index] === parseInt(number.dataset.num)) {
      clearInterval(intervals[index]);
    } else {
      counters[index] += 1;
      number.innerHTML = counters[index] + "%";
    }
  }, 20)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll("#number");
let counter = 0;
 numbers.forEach((number) => {
let myIntervalCounter = setInterval(() => {
        if(counter >= parseInt(number.dataset.num)){
            clearInterval(myIntervalCounter);
        }else{
            counter += 1;
            number.innerHTML = counter + "%";
        }
}, 20);
    });
```

```html
    <div class="skill-level position-absolute">
                <div class="outer">
                  <div class="inner d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <div id="number" data-num="95">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
                  <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
                    </linearGradient>
                  </defs>
                  <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
                </svg>
              </div>
                        <div class="skill-level position-absolute">
                <div class="outer">
                  <div class="inner d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <div id="number" data-num="70">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
                  <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
                    </linearGradient>
                  </defs>
                  <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
                </svg>
              </div>
```

- `>= parseInt(number.dataset.num)` use condition.
- `setInterval()` use in inside of `forEach()` loop.
- `clearInterval(intervalId);` set intervalId as argument.

Comment: thank you i did the same before but with === but it doesn't work but with >= it's work normally thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can't use id to select all same divs! the id must be unique!
if you want to select divs you must use class

```
<div class="number"> </div>
```

selector always select last element when they have same id

Comment: i changed from id to class but the problem still it count to infinty